# Xcode says I have 4.2 installed, but only 4.1 opens

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm confused about this. When I go on the market or try to download 4.2 to get ios5 it says that it is Installed. I check my Xcode in the about section and it says it is running 4.1. I tried this Install Xcode that is in my applications folder assuming maybe it was for the update and it still shows 4.1. How do I update my xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Applications folder, there is an app called **Install Xcode**. Run that to actually install Xcode4.2 after the App Store finishes downloading the upgrade. Weird, unexpected process, I know.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try again. Last time I ran that it still showed it as running 4.1. It might have been a problem I caused though because I had to stop it mid way through because of some issues and restarted it.

Comment: Ya I'm not sure what is up with it. I clicked and ran the Install Xcode. It did its "updating" and when it was done it made a little chime and opened Xcode. When I check the version it still shows 4.1. Any idea what is going on with it? Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are registered developer, you can just go to developer.apple.com, download the .dmg for Xcode4.2 (and make sure you get the package appropriate for your version of MacOS X, Leoopard or Lion), and install it that way.

Comment: Ok I'll show this step by step so you see what I'm seeing if I'm going somewhere wrong. First I go [here] (http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/) then I click to [here] (http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) at the bottom of that page it says Downloads: Xcode 4.2 and a button that says Download Xcode 4 next to it. It just takes me to the market place where the app is in which case it says that it is installed. Why is it that apple likes making things such a challenge?

Comment: Hmm.... not sure what to tell ya'. I see what you mean though. There must be a way to re-install an app installed via the App Store though. I don't know what it is though.

Comment: Hey if I uninstall xcode and reinstall it do you think that could work? That wouldn't delete the apps I already have made would it?

Comment: The trick would be to make the App Store think you don't have it installed anymore. And no, if you can uninstall Xcode, it will have no effect on your projects.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll try and see if I can get it. I'll mark you as solving it.

Comment: Ok, I have same problem as OP, but when I run "Install Xcode.app" from Applications/ it does its thing but I'm left with Xcode 4.1 still. Tried numerous times, with reboots etc. in between. Any ideas anyone?
I also ran the uninstall-devtools script, to see if that helped, but the same thing happened as usual when I ran the installer - 4.1, not 4.2

Comment: Thank you.  This new install process through the app store is lame.  This totally helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

The App Store doesn't upgrade Xcode 4.1 to Xcode 4.2 for you like it does for all other apps. Instead, it just downloads an installer/upgrader which gets placed in your Applications folder, and proceeds to not tell you anything about it, hoping you can read its mind. To upgrade, you have to do this:

1. Download the update via App Store.
2. Manually upgrade by running: `/Applications/Install Xcode`

---

Another way to do an upgrade will be to manually remove Xcode 4.x first:

1. Delete Xcode: `$ sudo rm -r /Developer` (takes about 20 minutes to finish)
2. Delete any "Install Xcode" files from your Applications folder.
3. Download Xcode 4.2 from the App Store.
4. When finished, install it: **Applications ---> Install Xcode**
5. Re-download all Xcode Documents and Components: **Xcode ---> Preferences ---> Downloads**

That's the most extreme way of doing things. If you added anything to your /Developer folder, you should back it up before running the `rm -r` command, as that will delete EVERYTHING in it.

Your Xcode preferences will remain in-tact, as they're stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/` and `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode......plist`

Comment: I've run the Install Xcode app many times, and each time it downloads and installs 4.1 again. Completely stumped now. The Mac App Store reports that Xcode is "Installed", so I can't do anything from in there (there's no uninstall or update option).

Comment: I added something to my answer. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After reading the answers here I looked for the "Install Xcode.app" file in the /Application directory and it wasn't there. It turns out that I had moved the "Install Xcode.app" bundle out of /Applications after I installed Xcode 4.1 (I didn't think it would be used again). I used Spotlight to remind me where I had moved it to and I ran it again and it updated the files. Now Xcode reports it is at version 4.2 like I expected. This is not at all like any other Apple installs. I wonder why they did it this way.

Answer (score 0):

follow the instructions given in http://simplecodebits.blogspot.com/2011/10/update-to-xcode-42-in-mac-osx-lion.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  However, when answering a question, it is best to put the actual answer in your reply, rather than a link to a different web page.