# Install XCode.app reinstalls Xcode 4.1 and not 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

This question is not a dupe of, but is very similar to, this question which has an accepted answer: [Xcode says I have 4.2 installed, but only 4.1 opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771565/xcode-says-i-have-4-2-installed-but-only-4-1-opens).

On my Mac's App Centre, it says Xcode is 'Installed' (and no option to uninstall or upgrade), but my current install of Xcode is actually 4.1 (with iOS 4.3 SDK). Following the advice of others, I've tried running `Install Xcode.app` from the Applications folder. This launches an installer that says "Installing Xcode 4" (note it doesn't give any minor version info like 4.1 or 4.2) -- it downloads and installs something. After installation, I still have Xcode 4.1 installed.

I've tried many reboots and also tried running the old `uninstall-devtools` script before running `Install Xcode.app` again, and no difference.

My machine is a Mid-2011 Mac Mini and it has no pending software updates available via `Apple Menu -> Software Update...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what worked for me:

I deleted `Install Xcode.app` from Applications, and then ran the following script:

```
/Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools
```

This is in a different location to before and I didn't spot it :/

Then run Mac App Store, search for Xcode, you should find there is now the option to install it.